# How to border bottom in rectangle in android

Tags: android

I want to give my button shape, only bottom line is colored with 2 dp size and rest of border part like left,top and right should be transparent. I have seen my example but they only color complete border. Even i have use LayerList element in my xml and try to give shape to bottom only but fail to create only bottom header. so please provide me solution

Comment: i thing to border in bottom you have to use some logic like take one layout color background blue and now in child take another background take background color as yello and on paren layout give it 2dp padding now you can see blue color border on yellow layout

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="YOUR LAYOUT COLOR"
>

<Button android:id="@+id/button" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="YOUR BUTTON COLOR"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"></Button>    

 </LinearLayout>
```

try this code

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 9-patch image. That should be the best way to achieve this.

I don't think you could achieve this my using shapes easily.

Have a look at the EditText ICS image samples to get an idea.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple hack to do this.

Step 1: Create a drawable xml file named `borderbutton.xml`, put in inside your `res/drawable` folder and copy this inside:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#0000" />
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
</shape>
```

You can then modify the `android:color` and the `android:bottom` values to better fit your needs.

step 2: in your Activity add this.

```
Button myButton = (Button)findElementById(R.id.yourButton);
myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borderbutton);
```

you can try this as well if that didn't work.

```
Drawable borderDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.borderbutton);
myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(borderDrawable);
```